# c# azure ad b2c: identity client requests permission on every API call

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I use this static service to get access to my database:

```cs
public static IPublicClientApplication IdentityClient { get; set; }
    
public static async Task<AuthenticationToken> GetAuthenticationToken()
{
    if (IdentityClient == null)
    {

        IdentityClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
         .Create(Constants.ClientId)
         .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "common")
         .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")
         .WithB2CAuthority(Constants.AuthoritySignIn)
         .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth")
         .Build();

    }
        
    var accounts = await IdentityClient.GetAccountsAsync();
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    bool tryInteractiveLogin = false;

    try
    {
        result = await IdentityClient
            .AcquireTokenSilent(Constants.Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
            .ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
    {
        tryInteractiveLogin = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MSAL Silent Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
        
    if (tryInteractiveLogin)
    {
        try
        {
            result = await IdentityClient
                .AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.Scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"MSAL Interactive Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
        
    var res = new AuthenticationToken
    {
        DisplayName = result?.Account?.Username ?? "",
        ExpiresOn = result?.ExpiresOn ?? DateTimeOffset.MinValue,
        Token = result?.AccessToken ?? "",
        UserId = result?.Account?.Username ?? ""
    };
        
    return res;
}
```

This kind of works fine. I am being returned a token and with which I can access my db. But the issue is for instance this:

```cs
var userDetail = new RemoteUserDetailService(SkillbasedAuthService.GetAuthenticationToken);
var detailUser = await userDetail.GetItemByUserId(user.Id);
if (detailUser.Count != 0)
    Helpers.LazyUser.AddUserDetailItemToLazyUser(detailUser[0]);
    
var picService = new RemotePictureService(SkillbasedAuthService.GetAuthenticationToken);
var picItem = await picService.GetUserThumbnailByuserId(user.Id);
```

Here I am accessing two different tables and both times I have to completely sign in on the azure portal: ofc I want to remain signed in and not have to type my password every time I request an API.

The issue must be the aforementioned code.
Maybe the Client cannot be static?

Anyone got any ideas?